# Is there any basis for the saying that 'Zamzam well will never dry out'?

Tags: authenticity

I have seen many claims about how the Zamzam well will never dry out. But, is there any backup for this from the Qur'an and Sunnah, implicit or explicit?

Answer (score 1):

As per [Islamweb](https://www.islamweb.net/en/article/138391/zamzam-water-the-history-significance-ii), there is an Ahmad hadith that says this:

> Ibn 'Abbaas, may Allah be pleased with him, narrated that the Prophet sallallaahu `alayhi wa sallam ( may Allah exalt his mention ) said: "...May Allah bestow his mercy upon her (Hagar, the mother of Ismaa’eel), had she let go (of the water of Zamzam) it would have become a spring (rather than a well) **whose water shall never dry**." [Ahmad]

Note: There's a similar hadith in [Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:3362) but it does not contain the "whose water shall never dry" portion.

I currently do not yet know of the exact Ahmad reference (book, hadith #). If someone can help find the specific reference, that would be great!

Comment: I think the hadith you refer to in Musnad Ahamd is [this](https://www.islamweb.net/hadith/display_hbook.php?bk_no=121&pid=60277&hid=2200&bk_no=121&pid=60277&hid=2200) even if the wording is not correctly translated as it says that the water will run until the day of Judgement. While all other narrations be it in Sahih al-Bukhari or elsewhere use the expression "flowing stream". See also the Takhreej -in Arabic.- [here](https://library.islamweb.net/hadith/hadithServices.php?type=1&cid=3075&sid=4883)

Comment: The narrator chain of this hadith in Musnad al--Imam Ahmad has been approved as Sahih by both Sho'aib al-Arnaoot (in his Takhreej al-Musnad) and Ahmad Shakir as you may find our by a quick serach of "يرحمُها اللهُ لو ترَكَتْها لكانت عينًا سائحةً تجري إلى يومِ القيامةِ" on [dorar.net](https://www.dorar.net)